# uploading the original image outside the publict_html root

Tags: php, filesystems

I’m uploading an image from a php form into the filesystem. Since the original image is high quality and because i don’t want to share it with nobody, I want to keep the original image in a safe place and make public the different sizes created from the original image

I’ve read that uploading the original image outside the publict_html root is a good option. Is this true? How do i keep the original image in a safe place and prevent it from being downloaded?

Thanks
Marco

Comment: what about the php script to output the original image (sometimes i need to open the original to look that its ok)... does it have to go outside the public_html root? If yes, is there a risk that someone can find the script and execute it and therefore download the original image?

Comment: no, and what security you put on a script is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth making a folder and settings apache / web server permissions to only allow leeching for verified users. Have a look at how you can authorise users with a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's true. User have only access to public_html directory. So, user can surf files and directories inside public_html, (assuming that there is no .htaccess or other security). So, you can say,

```
root/public_html      = www.example.com
root/public_html/img/ = www.example.com/img/
root/public_html      = www.example.com/img/../
```

But it's not possible to access root using "../",

```
root != www.example.com/../
```

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess .htpasswd are possible solutions; you can password protect the directory that has your image (since you need to access it).

if you want to prevent .jpg to be accessed in a directory on your server use the following .htaccess code in your directory:

```
# prevent reading of .jpg files
<Files *.jpg>
    Deny From All
</Files>
```

[Password Protect a directory](http://www.addedbytes.com/blog/code/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess/)
[.htaccess info](http://www.edginet.org/techie/website/htaccess.html)